# Stop Jenkins schedule build if it was failed more than 10 times?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I set my Jenkins job to build automaticlally many times a day by the scheduler.

If the build is failed, it will send mail to my team.

However I don't want to spamming the mail box. How can I set a condition to stop the build scheduler if it was failed more than 10 times ?

Comment: You can get the job to poll the SCM and only build if its changed, so you only get one email

Answer (score 1):

Rather than scheduling the job continuously, try the continuous integration paradigm, like this:

1. Unconditionally schedule the job only rarely.  Perhaps once per day, just to ensure than any external factors (missing resources, changed interfaces, etc.) haven't come into play.
2. Trigger the job when any known source or dependency changes (e.g. source code, jar in your artifact repository, DB schema change, etc.)
3. Use a suitable plugin to retry failures.

I recommend the [Naginator](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Naginator+Plugin) plugin for this.  It can nag a limited number of times, and it auto-throttles: it nags frequently to begin with, then less frequently after a protacted period of failure.

Even if you don't change how the job is trigger, Naginator is probably a good solution for you.  Use it to send your emails, instead of using an unconditional on-failure step.